# Ant BuildException error building Hadoop 2.2.0

Tags: maven, hadoop, ant, hadoop-yarn

I've been having trouble to build Hadoop 2.2.0 using Maven 3.1.1, this is part of the output I get (full log at http://pastebin.com/FE6vu46M):

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Main ................................ SUCCESS [27.471s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Project POM ......................... SUCCESS [0.936s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Annotations ......................... SUCCESS [3.819s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Assemblies .......................... SUCCESS [0.414s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Project Dist POM .................... SUCCESS [1.834s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Maven Plugins ....................... SUCCESS [4.693s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MiniKDC ............................. SUCCESS [4.346s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Auth ................................ SUCCESS [4.923s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Auth Examples ....................... SUCCESS [2.797s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Common .............................. FAILURE [22.898s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop NFS ................................. SKIPPED

..........

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:17.655s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Dec 04 16:18:31 CET 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 64M/420M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:
run (make) on project hadoop-common: An Ant BuildException has occured: exec returned: 1
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<exec dir="/home/scaino/hadoop-2.2.0-maven/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/target/native" 
executable="cmake" failonerror="true">... @ 4:135 in 
/home/scaino/hadoop-2.2.0-maven/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/target/antrun/build-main.xml
```

I've checked Protoc and it seems to be working, same with the library path, which is pointing to the libraries (installed in $HOME/install/lib):

```
~/hadoop-2.2.0-maven$ protoc --version
libprotoc 2.5.0

~/hadoop-2.2.0-maven$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/home/scaino/install/lib:/home/software/gcc-4.8/lib64:/home/software/mpich2-1.2.1/lib
```

This is some system information retrieved by Maven:

```
~/hadoop-2.2.0-maven$ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.1.1 (0728685237757ffbf44136acec0402957f723d9a; 2013-09-17 17:22:22+0200)
Maven home: /home/scaino/apache-maven-3.1.1
Java version: 1.7.0_25, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /home/software/jdk1.7.0_25/jre
Default locale: es_ES, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.35-32-server", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

I would appreciate any guidelines or hints that could make me understand what is going on since anything I've tried or seen has worked so far.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Regards,

Río

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be a library/compiler inconsistency in the node in which I was trying to compile the native libraries. Building in an updated node was enough to achieve a successful build.

Comment: How did you do that? Can you be more specific please?

Comment: The thing is some nodes' native library configuration were pretty messed up (several versions installed, symlinks everywhere...), so I was getting a lot of errors at compile, link and even execute time. That's why I moved to a clean and updated system and everything worked.

Comment: By the way, in order to have more info on what's going on with Maven, run with -X -e and check what happens in CMake logs. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have installed cmake in you machine. If you are using Ubuntu you can install cmake by using the following command

```
sudo apt-get install cmake
```

After installing the same, Try compiling...

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your folder name should not have spaces,
**/home/hadoop2.2/hadoop2.2-src** --- Build has no issues,

if your folder is like
**/home/hadoop 2.2/hadoop2.2-src** --- will get build issues.