# Compiling Hadoop occurs the error : org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An Ant BuildException has occured: exec returned: 2

Tags: maven, hadoop

The software I used as following:

apache-maven-3.0.5  findbugs-1.3.9  hadoop-2.7.3-src  jdk1.7 protobuf-2.5.0
[image]

And I meet the error as following:
[image]

The build-main.xml is as following:[image]

The system I used is Centos 7 and the JDK I used is 1.7.0_07. Anyone can help me to solve the problem?

Comment: could you please share the build-main.xml as well in the question

Comment: also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20381070/ant-buildexception-error-building-hadoop-2-2-0?rq=1

Comment: I have uploaded the build-main.xml.Could you help me check what's wrong?@nullpointer